# How do I catch a Constraint(Index) Violation in Grails?

Tags: mysql, exception, grails

Can't seem to find the right way to catch a MySQL index violation in a Grails app. Code from the controller:

```
try {
    configurationInstance.save(flush: true) {

    request.withFormat {...}
}

catch (JDBCException exception) {
    flash.error = "This would be a duplicate attribute, please change the suffix."
    render view: 'edit', model: [exception: exception]

}
```

When I provoke the error condition by submitting a duplicate value, the catch block is ignored and I get a 500 error page with these details:

*URI /itools/configuration/save*

*Class com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException*

*Message Duplicate entry '1009303-photo-recommendable-exclusion-pattern.2-0' for key 'publisher_config_uk'*

And in the console I've got:
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException occurred when processing request: [POST] /itools/configuration/save - parameters:
I've tried to catch

- JDBCException
- SQLError
- SQLException
- SQLDataException
- SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
- MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
- com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLDataException

all to no avail. (FWIW I also applied a *unique* constraint on the attribute in question and it does nothing when it should cause a validation error. That's a completely different issue.)

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: it's DuplicateKeyException.

(I had to catch the generic Exception and see it's details to find this.)

Now I've got a new problem: upon trying to render or redirect I get "null id in itools.Configuration entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)." This makes no sense to me -- the new entity was never saved to the DB because of the duplicate key, so why would a null ID object be a problem?